# cant retrieve JSON object on localhost

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to retrieve JSON Objects on my localhost, the issue is that it wont output anything. The JSON objects could look like following:

```
[
{
    NAME: "Hearthstone",
    PLAYER1: "Rdu ",
    PLAYER2: "Savjz ",
    status: 2,
    meta: "LIVE"
},
{
    NAME: "League of Legends",
    PLAYER1: "Team King ",
    PLAYER2: "EDG ",
    status: 2,
    meta: "28.12."
}]
```

php retrieve objects.

```
$url = "http://localhost:8888/crawl_JSON.php";
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$json_output = json_decode($json);


echo $json_output;
```

Why don't it output anything?

Comment: Are you sure that that link returns a json object?

Comment: Instead of using PHP to download, use a browser. Does that work sufficiently, i.e. return a 200 status code and the expected JSON data? If not, then you're looking in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `json_decode()` returns an object, you cannot `echo` you will need to use `var_dump` or `print_r`. If you want to echo , you can echo the JSON string.

```
$url = "http://localhost:8888/crawl_JSON.php";
$json = file_get_contents($url);
echo $json;
$json_output = json_decode($json);

var_dump($json_output);
```

And inside of **crawl_JSON.php** You need to `echo` the `JSON`, you will need to make sure it is valid.

```
<?php

echo '
[
    {
        "NAME": "Hearthstone",
        "PLAYER1": "Rdu ",
        "PLAYER2": "Savjz ",
        "status": 2,
        "meta": "LIVE"
    },
    {
        "NAME": "LeagueofLegends",
        "PLAYER1": "TeamKing",
        "PLAYER2": "EDG",
        "status": 2,
        "meta": "28.12."
    }
]
';
```

Comment: What's important is why not who

Comment: Why does it return null now?

Comment: @PeterPik because your JSON is not valid, see my edit

Comment: That might even be the cause for the OP's problems, @meda. Good catch!

Comment: i am echoing this $arr[]= array('NAME'=>$game,'PLAYER1'=>$opp1,'PLAYER2'=>$opp2, 'status' =>$status, 'meta'=>$meta); it seems valid to me.

Comment: @PeterPik I can tell you more if you show the code, make sure nothing else is echo'ed otherwise it will be invalid json

Comment: @PeterPik don't try to argue with the JSON interpreter, test your json here: http://jsonlint.org/ - it says: `Parse error on line 2:
[    {        NAME: "Hearthstone",
--------------^
Expecting 'STRING', '}'`

Comment: Now JSONLint says that it is valid, but the decode return null

Comment: @PeterPik Your script should return valid JSON only nothing else. json_decode only fails with invalid JSON. I cannot give you more pointers unless I see the script. But you can test my answer with the data hardcoded. What does `echo $json` outputs