# php JSON object returns null

Tags: php, json

i've finally made sure that my JSON objects slips through a JSON validator. However when i try to decode it returns null. my JSON object looks like following:

```
[
    {
        "NAME": "Hearthstone",
        "PLAYER1": "Rdu ",
        "PLAYER2": "Savjz ",
        "status": 2,
        "meta": "LIVE"
    },
    {
        "NAME": "LeagueofLegends",
        "PLAYER1": "TeamKing",
        "PLAYER2": "EDG",
        "status": 2,
        "meta": "28.12."
    }
]
```

php decode:

```
$json = file_get_contents("crawl_JSON.php");
$json_output = json_decode($json);

var_dump($json_output);
```

Comment: Make sure `crawl_JSON.php` isn't outputting anything before or after the JSON.

Comment: Haven't you been asked in your previous question to produce a minimal example? Please do that every time, this isn't going to help.

Comment: Seems like a full example to me, @UlrichEckhardt.  I put both in files and ran it and it worked (see my answer below).

Comment: @MarkMadej: Then it's not a full example, is it? A full example would reproduce the problem. A full example of something that works is not useful for a question asking why something else doesn't work.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit it worked for me, but he might have had some other issues.  I didn't run it EXACTLY as is, I modified a couple small things.  No biggie either way, looks like he got what he needed.

Comment: @MarkMadej: Right but this is a Q&A repository so we must ask and answer for the _general_ population. If this OP happened to get what _he_ needed then that's great but it only helps one specific person!

Comment: I suppose that's the ideal situation, @LightnessRacesinOrbit.  His question was pretty specific though (as are many on SO).  I'm just trying to help people write some code. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your php decode file, are you surrounding it with `<?` and `?>`?

It worked for me when I tried.  I assume the file with your JSON is named crawl_JSON.php, and it's in the same directory that you are executing the PHP file from?  If not, you may have to specify the full path.

More detail from my files:

crawl_JSON.php:

```
[
    {
        "NAME": "Hearthstone",
        "PLAYER1": "Rdu ",
        "PLAYER2": "Savjz ",
        "status": 2,
        "meta": "LIVE"
    },
    {
        "NAME": "LeagueofLegends",
        "PLAYER1": "TeamKing",
        "PLAYER2": "EDG",
        "status": 2,
        "meta": "28.12."
    }
]
```

test.php:

```
<?
$json = file_get_contents("crawl_JSON.php");
$json_output = json_decode($json);

var_dump($json_output);
?>
```

And my output from executing the program:

```
Marks-MacBook-Pro:stackOverflow mmadej$ php -f test.php 
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#1 (5) {
    ["NAME"]=>
    string(11) "Hearthstone"
    ["PLAYER1"]=>
    string(4) "Rdu "
    ["PLAYER2"]=>
    string(6) "Savjz "
    ["status"]=>
    int(2)
    ["meta"]=>
    string(4) "LIVE"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#2 (5) {
    ["NAME"]=>
    string(15) "LeagueofLegends"
    ["PLAYER1"]=>
    string(8) "TeamKing"
    ["PLAYER2"]=>
    string(3) "EDG"
    ["status"]=>
    int(2)
    ["meta"]=>
    string(6) "28.12."
  }
}
```

Comment: Why would the JSON file be named `.php`, when it is not a PHP script? That's crazy confusing. More likely it's actually a PHP script that outputs JSON when run, so Barmar's answer would be correct.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit In a previous question OP showed in some comments how he build it with PHP arrays, I have to admit Post is not complete

Comment: My guess is that he's just a new coder, and probably doesn't know the right way to do everything.  Otherwise he probably wouldn't be here with a relatively simple question.  I think crawl_JSON.php is clearly a JSON file (not PHP) just based on the contents.

Comment: see [op comments here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27669997/cant-retrieve-json-object-on-localhost#comment43755162_27670023)

Comment: @MarkMadej: Then can we suggest strongly to him that he renames it? You can see on this page alone that it's caused great confusion.

Comment: @Peter: Can you explain what the solution was for you? There are several suggestions in this answer.

Answer (score 2):

PHP scripts aren't run if you access them as ordinary files, you have to access them through the webserver. So change it to:

```
$json = file_get_contents("http://localhost/crawl_JSON.php");
```

That assumes the script is in the document root, you probably need to add the full path from the document root to the script.